# direct11 write data to buffer in pixel shader? (like ssbo in open)

Tags: directx, monogame, hlsl

I'm trying to write data to a buffer in hlsl shader. I know in opengl you need ssbo, but is there a corresponding buffer type in direct11?(I'm new to it).

p.s. I'm using monogame so the newest shader model available is 3.0.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shader Model 3 corresponds to the DirectX 9 architecture. This architecture looks as follows:

[image: DX9 Pipeline]
<sub>(source: [s-msft.com](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC412590.png))</sub>

(Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219679(v=vs.85).aspx)

As you see, there is only one output from the pixel shader. This output can be a color or depth value and will be rendered to the render target. So, there is no way in DX9.

In DX10 (SM 4), the pipeline looks as follows:

[image: DX10 pipeline]
<sub>(source: [s-msft.com](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC412557.png))</sub>

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205123(v=vs.85).aspx

Again, the output of the pixel shader is color and depth. No way in DX10 either.

Finally, DirectX 11 (SM 5):

[image: DX11 pipeline]
<sub>(source: [s-msft.com](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC340510.jpg))</sub>

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476882(v=vs.85).aspx

Now there is a way from the Pixel Shader to Memory Resources. The buffer type that you would need is the [RWBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/sm5-object-rwbuffer).

Comment: merci beaucoup, I guess I have to render to a texture first then do some processing of it.